# php add dots to a variable received from load function

Tags: php

I receive a variable through jquery

```
var x = 15;
$("#block").load("file.php", {n:x});
```

When i try to use it

```
$i=$_POST['n'];  
echo $i;
```

i receive that :  .15.

My question is - How to delete this dots.
And why they are appear.

Comment: `var_dump($i)` – ensure what exactly is in that variable when you get it. Sure you don't happen to be outputting a `.` before this somewhere?

Comment: For that, we'd have to see the entire PHP code, you're probably sending the _"."_ as output elsewhere. Check to see if the opening tag isn't preceded by a dot (as in `.<?php`)

Comment: no I have near 200 lines of php file and I'm sure that nowhere is dots (as in .<?php). Dump give you string(4) ".15."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete dots:

```
<?php
$i = trim($_POST['n']);

// delete first dot (if exists)
if(substr($i, 0, 1) == '.') $i = substr($i, 1);
// delete last dot (if exists)
if(substr($i, -1) == '.') $i = substr($i, 0, -1);

echo $i;
?>
```

Comment: Protip: `trim($i, '.')`